# How to use getpagesize(2) to get the size of a file after opening it

Tags: c, unix

i have a file hello.txt
and a pointer *i pointing to the file, i have opened the file using c open(*i) function. i want to get the size of file using getpagesize(2) to read the content of the file and further write that content to a destination file. so getting the size of the file i required to now how big is the file and how much content there is to read.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You will get better answers if you edit your post to actually *include* the relevant code.  Also describe what you think the `getpagesize` function does and why you think you want to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `open` system function to open the file, you should look into the [`fstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) function to get the size:

```
int fd = open(...);

struct stat st;
fstat(fd, &st);

printf("File size: %ld bytes\n", st.st_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getpagesize` only tells you how big the memory pages are on the system; it has nothing to do with files. You should look at the [`stat`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) call; it does what you need.

If operating on `FILE *`, you can use `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)` and `ftell(f)` to figure out how long the file is.